# How do I add /opt/nginx to my path variables, so I can use nginx in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, path, nginx

I installed nginx recently, and it is found at /opt/nginx... asking "which nginx" doesn't find nginx, and I can't figure out how to use nginx.  I think it's because nginx is installed in the opt directory.

How can I add the opt directory to my paths?  Is this even what I want to do??  I just want to be able to run a nginx server locally for development purposes.

Also, is there some document online I can read to understand what is going on better.  I know I don't know enough about how this all works, as I'm not a super user of my computer.  I'm more of a programmer.  BUT - I'd like to learn more, but I don't know where to begin.

Comment: Maybe this question/answer will help you: http://superuser.com/questions/284342/how-do-i-set-path-and-other-environment-variables

Answer (score 1):

> [`/opt`](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_beginner_books/linux_filesystem/opt.html)
>
> reserved for all the software and add-on packages that are not part of the default installation

It's fine to [add this directory to your PATH](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/how-do-i-set-path-and-other-environment-variables). As the paths are processed from left to right make sure you add yours to the end so that any files in `/opt` won't have higher priority than your system binaries.

If you don't add it to your PATH, you need to run it by `/opt/nginx` everytime. Or `cd /opt; nginx`.